# Javascript not working in the render partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to include some JS files and execute JS script on DOM is ready in  `partial page`

But it doesn't work.

If I move the `JS code block` into layout page, it works.

But I don't want to execute the JS code in every page.

Any idea?

## index page

```
= render 'data_range'
```

## partial page : _data_range.html.haml (Not working)

```
    %script{:src => asset_path("kode/js/date-range-picker/daterangepicker.js"), :type => "text/javascript"}
    = javascript_include_tag 'common'
    / = javascript_include_tag params[:controller]
    :javascript
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#date-range-picker').daterangepicker(null, function(start, end, label) {
          console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
        });
      });
```

## layout page : layouts/application.html.haml (works!!)

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title= t("site_name")
    = render 'layouts/mobile/common_header'
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application" 
    = javascript_include_tag params[:controller]
  %body
    = yield
    %script{:src => asset_path("kode/js/date-range-picker/daterangepicker.js"), :type => "text/javascript"}
    = javascript_include_tag 'common'
    / = javascript_include_tag params[:controller]
    :javascript
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#date-range-picker').daterangepicker(null, function(start, end, label) {
          console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, the easiest way to do that, is a separate JavaScript partial on your layout page. This is what I do (simplified):

#### create the partial `views/application/_javascript.html.haml`

```rb
= javascript_include_tag 'common'
= javascript_include_tag params[:controller] 
= yield :additional_js
```

#### add this partial at the end of the body to you layout

```rb
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title= t("site_name")
    = render 'layouts/mobile/common_header'
    = stylesheet_link_tag    "application" 
  %body
    = yield
    = render 'javascript'
```

#### now in your partial `_data_range.html.haml` do a content_for

```
- content_for :additional_js do
  %script{:src => asset_path("kode/js/date-range-picker/daterangepicker.js"), :type => "text/javascript"}

  :javascript
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#date-range-picker').daterangepicker(null, function(start, end, label) {
        console.log(start.toISOString(), end.toISOString(), label);
      });
    });
```

In this way, you can write page specific JavaScript and have it rendered in the layout. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi your answer is helpful, and may you please simply explain about what my code didn't work ? I supposed it could be working, if i put the JS code after the DOM element

Comment: Hard to tell with the given code. Do you define the element `#date-range-picker` before, or after the js code? I need more information. Can you update `_data_range.html.haml` in your post, or wherever you define `#date-range-picker`?